# How do I modify the ManyToMany submission form from "hold ctrl to select multiple"

Tags: django, forms, many-to-many, user-input

I'm making a medication tracking site in Django and am having trouble assigning multiple times to a medication. Currently I have a model for the Medication:

```
class Medication(models.Model):
UNDEFINED = ''
MILIGRAMS = 'mg'
MILIEQUIVILENT = 'MEQ'
MILILITERS = 'ml'

MEASUREMENT_CHOICES = [
    (UNDEFINED, ' '),
    (MILIGRAMS, 'mg'),
    (MILIEQUIVILENT, 'MEQ'),
    (MILILITERS, 'ml'),
]

ORAL = 'orally'
OPTICALLY = 'optically'
NASALLY = 'nasally'
OTTICALLY = 'per ear'
SUBLINGUAL = 'sublingual'
SUBCUTANEOUS = 'subcutaneous'
PER_RECTUM = 'per rectum'
TOPICAL = 'topical'
INHALATION = 'inhalation'

ROUTE_CHOICES = [
    (ORAL, 'orally'),
    (OPTICALLY, 'optically'),
    (NASALLY, 'nasally'),
    (OTTICALLY, 'per ear'),
    (SUBLINGUAL, 'sublingual'),
    (SUBCUTANEOUS, 'subcutaneous'),
    (PER_RECTUM, 'per rectum'),
    (TOPICAL, 'topical'),
    (INHALATION, 'inhalation'),
]

AS_NEEDED = "PRN"
EVERY = "every"
EVERY_TWO = "every two"
EVERY_THREE = "every three"
EVERY_FOUR = "every four"
EVERY_FIVE = "every five"
EVERY_SIX = "six"
EVERY_SEVEN = "seven"
EVERY_EIGHT = "eight"
EVERY_NINE = "nine"

FREQUENCY_NUM = [
    (AS_NEEDED, "PRN"),
    (EVERY, "every"),
    (EVERY_TWO, "every two"),
    (EVERY_THREE, "every three"),
    (EVERY_FOUR, "every four"),
    (EVERY_FIVE, "every five"),
    (EVERY_SIX, "six"),
    (EVERY_SEVEN, "seven"),
    (EVERY_EIGHT, "eight"),
    (EVERY_NINE, "nine"),
]

MINUTE = 'minute'
HOUR = "hour"
DAY = "day"
WEEK = 'week'
MONTH = "month"

FREQUENCY_MEASUREMENT = [
    (MINUTE, 'minute'),
    (HOUR, "hour"),
    (DAY, "day"),
    (WEEK, 'week'),
    (MONTH, "month"),
]

ONE_TAB = 'tab'
MULTIPLE_TABS = 'tabs'
HALF_TAB = 'half of a tab'
THIRD_TAB = 'third of a tab'
QUARTER_TAB = 'quarter of a tab'
ONE_DROP = 'drop'
MULTIPLE_DROPS = 'drops'

FORM_FACTORS = [
    (ONE_TAB, 'tab'),
    (MULTIPLE_TABS, 'tabs'),
    (HALF_TAB, 'half of a tab'),
    (THIRD_TAB, 'third of a tab'),
    (QUARTER_TAB, 'quarter of a tab'),
    (ONE_DROP, 'drop'),
    (MULTIPLE_DROPS, 'drops')
]

client = models.ForeignKey(
    Client_Medlist,
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
drug_class = models.CharField(max_length=255)
dosage = models.FloatField(default=10)
measurement = models.CharField(
    max_length=3,
    choices=MEASUREMENT_CHOICES,
    default=MILIGRAMS,)
number_of_form = models.IntegerField(default=1)
drug_form_factor = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    choices=FORM_FACTORS,
    default=ONE_TAB,
)

route = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    choices=ROUTE_CHOICES,
    default=ORAL,)
frequency_num = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    choices=FREQUENCY_NUM,
    default=EVERY,)
frequency_measurement = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    choices=FREQUENCY_MEASUREMENT,
    default=DAY,)

times_taken = models.ManyToManyField(Medication_Times)

start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
is_med_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

transcription_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
transcription_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

This model has a 'ManyToMany' relation to the medication times model:

```
class Medication_Times(models.Model):
times_taken = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

display_name = models.CharField(default='Scheduled Time', max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
return self.times_taken.strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

For the view leading to this page I am using LoginRequiredMixin and CreateView:

```
class MedicationNew(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Medication
template_name = 'client_profile/new_med.html'
context_object_name = 'posts'
fields = ['client', 'name', 'start_date', 'drug_class', 'dosage', 'measurement', 'route', 'frequency_num', 'frequency_measurement', 'times_taken']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

This all works well, but where the maximum value between times is fifteen minutes, when the user is creating a new medication to add to a client's chart, the times are displayed in a long scrolling list with only ctrl+click to select multiple.

Where this needs to be as user friendly as possible, I was thinking that selecting a time, then adding it to a box displayed below the scrolling selection might be a better approach. This way if a user selects the wrong thing, it would be in the box for easy removal, and would be easy to scroll back and select the correct time(s). Then after the correct time(s) are chosen, the whole form could be submitted.

Is there a straightforward way to do this in Django? I have been looking everywhere for a manner to do so, but have yet to come up with anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.